# I am a beginner to flutter I am using the date_picker_timeline widget, I wanted the date picker to jump to a specific date when I pressed the button

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, floating-action-button

I am using the `date_picker_timeline` widget and I wanted the date picker to jump to a specific date when I pressed the floating action button. But it's not working as intended. Here is my code.

##### main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Date Picker"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [datePickerMethod()],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //This is not jumping to the given date
          DatePickerController().animateToDate(DateTime(2021, 10, 10));
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

DatePicker datePickerMethod() {
  return DatePicker(
    DateTime.now(),
    initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
    selectionColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
  );
}
```

##### pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: date_picker_demo
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answered

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

DatePickerController dp = DatePickerController();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Date Picker"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [datePickerMethod()],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //Fixed
          dp.animateToDate(DateTime(2021, 10, 10));
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

DatePicker datePickerMethod() {
  return DatePicker(
    DateTime.now(),
    controller: dp,
    initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
    selectionColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
  );
}
```